# Dynamically create Bulk custom Fields at a single shot

Tags: custom-field, metadata-api

Is there any way to create bulk fields in salesforce. For example. If i want to have 10 custom text fields, i want a interface by which i create 10 custom text fields for an object with a different name at a single shot.

Answer (score 3):

Adding fields dynamically may not be a good design unless its really required.

Salesforce Metadata API is a way out to create fields dynamically. This API can be called from different language app as well. And make sure to have System Admin role before running this code.

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
customField.fullName = 'CustomObject__c.CustomField__c';
customField.label = 'Custom Field';
customField.type_x = 'Text';
customField.length = 10;
MetadataService.AsyncResult[] results =
    service.create(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { customField });
```